# In Python, how can I export a 3D isosurface into Blender

Tags: python, scipy, blender, mayavi

I have some 3D (x,y,z,value) data in python and I can visualize the isosurfaces in Mayavi. How can I export this isosurface into a file that I can read into Blender?

Here is some example code:

```
import numpy
from mayavi import mlab

x, y, z = numpy.ogrid[-5:5:64j, -5:5:64j, -5:5:64j]
values = x * x * 0.5 + y * y + z * z * 2.0
mlab.contour3d(values, contours=[.5])
mlab.show()
```

Comment: Answer to this may well help with unanswered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122004/how-to-write-stl-file-within-python-mayavi too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using @timday's suggestion, I added the following code to save the isosurface in a wavefront (.obj) format:

mlab.savefig('surface.obj')

Then, I can open it in Blender with File>>Import>>Wavefront (.obj)

I had to scale down the image considerably (~100x) to make it visible in the Blender viewport.

[image]

The origin is set way off to the side of the actual object, so the object is easier to deal with if I use Object>>Transform>>Origin to Geometry

[image]

After adding some lighting and a plane, the object looks pretty good!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it myself but I notice mlab's [savefig](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_figure.html#savefig) also claims to support saving to Wavefront ".obj" format (also known as [wavefront format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)), a 3D geometry format.  Certainly I've seen [importers from obj to Blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Wavefront_OBJ#Wavefront_OBJ_Import.2FExport).