# How do I open .mhd file corresponding to a .raw file in Blender 3D tool?

Tags: 3d, blender

How do I open 3D medical images in .mhd format linked to .raw files in Blender 3D tool. I have already installed the .raw add-on but it is not helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading \*.mhd/\*.raw format in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290631/reading-mhd-raw-format-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SimpleITK](http://www.simpleitk.org/) in Python to load in the data, [convert to a Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38517378/3988037), then use a python script to extract the 3D array, and export that to a Blender-digestible format. [Take a look at this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772280/in-python-how-can-i-export-a-3d-isosurface-into-blender) for how to convert the volume into an isosurface, then export that surface into Blender.